# How to access custom fields from order in thank you page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a lot of custom fields I have created in my order, I am trying to now access them when the order is completed on the thank you page.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394139/woocommerce-get-custom-select-fields-value-at-thank-you-page) response but it does not work for me. I do a var dump to see what's inside of `$order->order_custom_fields` but I just get `string(0) ""`

I am editing the file order-details-customer.php  How can I access my custom fields?

Here is an example of a custom field I have created

```
        woocommerce_form_field( 'destination_state', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('destination_state form-row-first'),
        'label'         => __('State'),
        'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'destination_state' ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching and just logical thinking I figured out that it's very easy.

```
echo '<p>' . get_post_meta(  $order->id, 'Date Collection', true ) . '</p>';
```